# Formula not applying dynamc arrays to all rows in dataframe

Tags: python, loops, vector, technical-indicator

I'm working on a modified technical analysis indicator consisting of 3 "Workings". The dataframe (df) consists of daily closing prices for IBM that includes the date, ticker and close price for IBM for the last year:

```
    date    ticker  close
227 2023-07-03 04:00:00 IBM 133.669998
228 2023-07-05 04:00:00 IBM 134.240005
229 2023-07-06 04:00:00 IBM 132.160004
230 2023-07-07 04:00:00 IBM 132.080002
231 2023-07-10 04:00:00 IBM 132.899994
232 2023-07-11 04:00:00 IBM 134.440002
233 2023-07-12 04:00:00 IBM 132.839996
234 2023-07-13 04:00:00 IBM 133.919998
235 2023-07-14 04:00:00 IBM 133.399994
236 2023-07-17 04:00:00 IBM 134.240005
237 2023-07-18 04:00:00 IBM 135.360001
238 2023-07-19 04:00:00 IBM 135.479996
239 2023-07-20 04:00:00 IBM 138.380005
240 2023-07-21 04:00:00 IBM 138.940002
241 2023-07-24 04:00:00 IBM 139.539993
242 2023-07-25 04:00:00 IBM 140.330002
243 2023-07-26 04:00:00 IBM 141.070007
244 2023-07-27 04:00:00 IBM 142.970001
245 2023-07-28 04:00:00 IBM 143.449997
246 2023-07-31 04:00:00 IBM 144.179993
```

workings1 generates the correct answer of (211.89) which applies to the 2023-07-31 date only. I cannot figure out how to apply this formula to all the previous rows (less the lag of n).

```
n = 14
workings1 = (np.inner(np.squeeze(np.array(df['close'])[-n:]), np.arange(0,n))) - (1/n * np.sum(np.arange(0,n)) * np.sum(np.squeeze(np.array(df['close'])[-n:])))
print(workings1)
```

Breaking this apart:

```
np.array(df['close'])[-n:] = array([132.83999634, 133.91999817, 133.3999939 , 134.24000549,
       135.36000061, 135.47999573, 138.38000488, 138.94000244,
       139.53999329, 140.33000183, 141.07000732, 142.97000122,
       143.44999695, 144.17999268]) #This array should change based upon the row(date) column. It's the lag of the last n days
np.arange(0,n) = array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13]) #This doesn't change
```

I tried defining a function:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

rolling_array = rolling_window(df['close'].to_numpy(),14)
```

Output:

```
array([[126.00315857, 126.12680054, 124.69179535, ..., 130.54742432,
        129.76730347, 128.31300354],
       [126.12680054, 124.69179535, 126.64687347, ..., 129.76730347,
        128.31300354, 129.03533936],
       [124.69179535, 126.64687347, 127.64847565, ..., 128.31300354,
        129.03533936, 125.56821442],
       ...,
       [132.8999939 , 134.44000244, 132.83999634, ..., 140.33000183,
        141.07000732, 142.97000122],
       [134.44000244, 132.83999634, 133.91999817, ..., 141.07000732,
        142.97000122, 143.44999695],
       [132.83999634, 133.91999817, 133.3999939 , ..., 142.97000122,
        143.44999695, 144.17999268]])
```

I've run into shape issues due to the lag (n)

I know that it can probably be looped, but I can't even make a loop run correctly. Any help would be fantastic... especially if this can be vectored for a large DF. Thanks

**---Solved---**
for posterity

```
n=14
# create a function
def technical_analysis(seqs):
    seq = seqs.values
    n = len(seq)
    workings1 = (np.inner(seq, np.arange(0,n))) - (1/n * np.sum(np.arange(0,n)) * np.sum(seq))
    workings2 = np.sum(np.power(np.arange(0,n),2)) - 1 / n * np.power(np.sum(np.arange(0,n)),2)
    workings3 = (np.sum(np.power(seq,2))) - (1/n * np.power(np.sum(seq),2))
    return  workings1 / np.sqrt(workings2 * workings3)

# and apply the function
tech = df['close'].rolling(n).apply(technical_analysis)
```